# angular 6 library consumer can't resolve libray

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm having issues with creating a hello world library project and consuming that by npm installing it from our local registry.

I keep getting this error message in my library consumer app:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(4,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-test-lib'.
```

The library package is getting installed into the nodemodules folder just fine.  Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Here is the contents of the package.json that was bundled in the npm package:

```
{
  "_from": "ng-test-lib@prerelease",
  "_id": "ng-test-lib@0.0.0-b20180829144257",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-9oOX6tB+HdvHfOWVbv8fFEC3WpxPd7nvHn6bBMAGlPP6/2RumidYFQLYCSdSE+w7pjF96PippgTBK8DUxkxEMw==",
  "_location": "/ng-test-lib",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "tag",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "ng-test-lib@prerelease",
    "name": "ng-test-lib",
    "escapedName": "ng-test-lib",
    "rawSpec": "prerelease",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "prerelease"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "http://nexus/content/groups/alm_public_read_npm/ng-test-lib/-/ng-test-lib-0.0.0-b20180829144257.tgz",
  "_shasum": "c3de3039fe37908292834d4edac893a8f118a28f",
  "_spec": "ng-test-lib@prerelease",
  "_where": "C:\\lib-client",
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "deprecated": false,
  "name": "ng-test-lib",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0-b20180829144257"
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to import it:

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {NgTestLibModule} from 'ng-test-lib';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgTestLibModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any pointers as to how i can resolve the issue here?  The library itself is just a hello world library, no external dependencies or anything, just trying to prove out the path for now.

Thanks!

---- EDIT

So it looks like specifying a main attribute in projects/ng-test-lib/package.json fixed my issue, but my question is why doesn't Angular's library scaffolding add the main attribute into the package.json file when it gens the library?

Adding

```
{
  "name": "ng-test-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main":"fesm2015/ng-test-lib.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

is it bad practice for me to add the main attribute?

Comment: The seems like it could be an IDE thing. Have you closed and reopened your IDE since installing the library? I use VS Code, and sometimes it just doesn't pick these things up without a reload.

Comment: yes I have restarted the ide, nuked the node_modules folder, and even had a colleague install it and reproduced the error

Comment: You don't need to manually add "main" entry to your compiled library. Something must be wrong. Mine was working perfectly without any manual process. Simply `ng build --prod library-name` worked for me.

Comment: Does your build step add the main attribute in the generated package.json under dist/yourlib/?